# Capitalize last character if its starts and ends with specific characters

Tags: python, pandas

I need to capitalize the last character if it starts with 'abc' and end with 'n'. I have come up written the below code but i cant seem to get it to work, any correction/input is highly appriciated

```py
bhp['cc']=bhp['cc'].apply( lambda x:x[0:-1] + x[-1].upper() if(x.startswith('abc') & x.endswith('n')))
```

Comment: Sample data that you want this applied on?

Comment: First of all, your syntax is wrong. You need and `if` and `else` clause. Second, would be nice to check a sample input/output cause it seems you don't need this messy lambda function inside the apply

Comment: Do you intend to capitalize the last char `n` or the one before it?

Comment: a or b or c, or sentence abc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` statement is missing so `apply` doesn't know what to do if the condition fails. By adding `else x` after the `if` condition, it will work.

```
apply(lambda x:x[0:-1] + x[-1].upper() if(x.startswith('abc') & x.endswith('n')) else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This capitalizes the last char (before `n`) and lower-cases the rest:

```
s = 'abcdirtybitn'

print(s[:-2].lower() + s[-2:].capitalize() if s.startswith('abc') and s.endswith('n') else s)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
abcdirtybiTn
```

If you want the last char `n` capitalized:

```
print(s[:-1].lower() + s[-1:].capitalize() if s.startswith('abc') and s.endswith('n') else s)  # abcdirtybitN
```

**EDIT**:

If you do not want to manipulate/lower-case all the rest:

```
s = 'abcDirtyBitn'

print(s[:-1] + s[-1:].capitalize() if s.startswith('abc') and s.endswith('n') else s)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
abcDirtyBitN
```

**AND**:

```
s = 'abcDirtyBitn'

print(s[:-2] + s[-2:].capitalize() if s.startswith('abc') and s.endswith('n') else s)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
abcDirtyBiTn
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be one efficient solution:

```
In [47]: l
Out[47]: ['abcdfn', 'abc', 'abcn', 'Acv', 'Abc']

In [48]: df = pd.DataFrame(l)

In [49]: df
Out[49]:
        0
0  abcdfn
1     abc
2    abcn
3     Acv
4     Abc

In [50]: mask = df[0].str.startswith('abc') & df[0].str.endswith('n')

In [51]: df.loc[mask, 0] = df[mask][0].apply(lambda x : x[0:-1] + x[-1].upper())

In [52]: df
Out[52]:
        0
0  abcdfN
1     abc
2    abcN
3     Acv
4     Abc
```

Comment: `I think this can be one efficient solution:` - why do you think so?

Comment: You run the operation on a view on the data instead of the whole vector. I have not benchmark for this task it so I may be wrong.